# How long does it take an investment to quadruple in value if it earns 5% simple interest per year?

Tags: finance

How long does it take an investment to quadruple in value if it earns 5% simple interest per year?

I'm not sure about how to find it but the Awnser: 60 years

Answer (score 4):

Say the investment amount is $P$ and takes $\color{blue}{T}$ years to grow to $4P$ :

$$P + P*0.05*\color{blue}{T} = 4P$$

Divide $P$ through out and get
$$1 + 0.05*\color{blue}{T} = 4$$

See if you can take it home from here..